# What happened to reports in QB API V2 and 3?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I played with the Intuit AnyWhere API about a year ago and at that time, there were some reporting entities such as the balance sheet and income statement. I notice now in V2 and V3, all that has disappeared. Does anyone know if there are any plans to add it back in? Seems like a fairly large omission given the functionality of the QB SDK.

Answer (score 3):

In v2, the reports are definitely still supported for QuickBooks Desktop. Docs are here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/064_reports

QuickBooks Online has never supported any form of reporting.

As far as v3 goes, it's still in private beta, so everything is pretty much still up in the air on that still.